# How can i add multiple HTML files to WebKit View?

Tags: ios, swift

**Introduction**

I'm designing a historical application.I want to add multiple `HTML` files into 
`WebKit` View. I don't have any idea how to do this.

**Example**

When I click to `"Button 1"` webkit loads `"file1.html"`. I didn't write anything about code I am quite confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a lot of ways to do it but I'm gonna give an example for easiest one. Just create a method for loading ***.html*** file and invoke or call it under action button.

For example :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ExampleController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.navigationDelegate = self

}

@IBAction func firstButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Here you can call your method to load html page.
    loadPage(pageName: "privacy_policy")        
}

@IBAction func secondButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
     // Here you can call different html page.
    loadPage(pageName: "terms")
}

// With this method you can call html page by it name (as parameter)
fileprivate func loadPage(pageName: String) {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pageName, withExtension: "html")
    // file url is ready lets to add it as parameter for webView.
    webView.loadFileURL(url!, allowingReadAccessTo: url!)
}
}

extension AboutAppController: WKNavigationDelegate {

   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
       // Here you can add start your animations (like activity indicator)
   }

   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
       // And here finish your animations.
   }
}
```